# Dynamically generating a QR code with PHP

Tags: php, qr-code

I'm trying to generate QR codes on my website. All they have to do is have a URL in them, which a variable on my site will provide. What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: don't re-invent the wheel! below answers are perfect

Comment: Akor: could you please un-accept my answer? Google has [deprecated the API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?csw=1) upon which my answer relies, therefore it serves little purpose from now on.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

It's worth adding that, in addition to the QR codes library posted by [@abaumg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php/5943375#5943375), Google provides a <del>[QR Codes API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/qr_codes.html)</del> [QR Codes API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html)<sup>many thanks to [@Toukakoukan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336783/toukakoukan) for the [link update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php/5943398#comment-8803253)</sup>.

To use this, basically:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8
```

- `300x300` is the size of the QR image you want to generate,
- the `chl` is the url-encoded string you want to change into a QR code, and
- the `choe` is the (optional) encoding.

The link, above, gives more detail, but to use it just have the `src` of an image point to the manipulated value, like so:

```html
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com" />
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Original link to the API has broken as the [page has now moved here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html)

Comment: Are there any limitations for using the Google API?. I mean limitations as: amount of requests in a given time, etc.

Comment: @Lobo: not of which I'm currently aware, no. Though this may change over time, of course.

Comment: It should be noted that this has been deprecated. Google plans to continue support until 2015. So as always, caveat emptor.

Comment: @Lobo According to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts): "*There's no limit to the number of calls per day you can make to the Google Chart API. However, we reserve the right to block any use that we regard as abusive.*".

Comment: I find answer by @abaumg better as it does not depends 3rd parties like google...

Comment: have they come up with any alternatives ? I read Google is sunsetting charts API (QR Code) around April 2015.

Comment: As of March 2015, Google QR Code API is deprecated

Comment: @mmcrae: so I see, thank you. I've notified the OP (in a comment to the question) asking to be unaccepted, to allow this question to retain use for the future.

Comment: you could also just delete your answer, or edit it with a disclaimer / alternative answer, no?

Comment: @mmcrae: I'm not sure I could, the likely way I'd go, from my current answer, would be to recommend a library, which [abaumg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943375/82548) has already done; there may be a *better* library, now, after all this time, but I've not yet come across one. Though my research has been extremely casual. And recommending an external resource is now considered off-topic for Stack Overflow, so I'd rather not run that risk in addition to the risk of posting a likely-duplicate answer.

Comment: Do you think this answer is contributing something to the discussion? To me, it seems not, as it is suggesting to use something that should not be used. Unless I'm mistaken, and you can actually use the Google QR Code API without issues. If I knew my answer was no longer helpful or was misguided, I would remove it to save others the time of discovering the issues themselves.

Comment: @mmcrae: no, I can't; not while it's accepted. That's why I've requested to be unaccepted, so that I *can* delete it. I've also flagged for moderator attention, so that they might be able to take action on my behalf (overriding the "you can't delete this accepted answer" rule).

Comment: @anon gotchya :) didn't know about that rule. I wonder if that's a limitation on the way they designed the application / database for SO...

Comment: @anon I've flagged this as "for moderator intervention" to see if a mod can perhaps un-accept the answer (it was a valid and relevant answer at the time of posting but is no longer so). This SO question comes up as the second result for "php qr code library" (how I got here) so I think it's important that the question remain up-to-date even if the OP is no longer paying attention.

Comment: current link is deprecated , here is the updated link

Comment: the best of google product

Comment: This API has now been turned off by Google and can no longer be used.

Comment: Sept 2019 - still working as of now!

Comment: Downvoting because of the PHP tag - this is not a PHP solution.

Comment: 2021 and still working :D

Comment: May 2022, still working

Comment: Oct 2022, still working... but it timesout after 4 calls in quick succession

Comment: This API is now failing for us - intermittently. Need to replace it with another solution. Outsourcing such a simple and cheap task to a third party seems overkill to me though, so I would recommend bringing in a library/package whenever possible.

Comment: Jan 2024, still working

Answer (score 106):

The easiest way to generate QR codes with PHP is the [phpqrcode library](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 this answers the question more closely, you can generate the QR code on your own, without being limited by the Google limits enforced for requests.
This will also make sure that your website works, even when the google endpoint contract changes.

Comment: Fair warning:  It looks like this library may be "dead" - it hasn't been updated by the author since October 2010 and has a couple of patches in the issue tracker that users of the library should consider applying before using the library.

Comment: but how to convert it into mvc standard any ideas !!!!

Comment: @CubicleSoft i think developer took your comment seriously and updated right away

Comment: @mokNathal - I'm not seeing anything different here.  The most recent release available on the Downloads page is still from 2010.

Comment: @CubicleSoft sorry my bad i saw last update date on summary page

Comment: I wanted to use it WITHOUT composer but it did not work in Ubuntu although it works in Windows. I was pleased to see Composer support is a fairly recent addition and that by downloading the last commit before Composer support was added I was able to forget about Composer and get the library working in seconds.

https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder/tree/cda63b7f4a8cd84d72c41b25c74284b56dc7f2cc

It works very well now...

Answer (score 33):

The [endroid/QrCode library](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode) is easy to use, well maintained, and can be installed using composer. There is also a [bundle](https://github.com/endroid/EndroidQrCodeBundle) to use directly with Symfony.

Installing :

```
$ composer require endroid/qrcode
```

Usage :

```
<?php

use Endroid\QrCode\QrCode;

$qrCode = new QrCode();
$qrCode
    ->setText('Life is too short to be generating QR codes')
    ->setSize(300)
    ->setPadding(10)
    ->setErrorCorrection('high')
    ->setForegroundColor(array('r' => 0, 'g' => 0, 'b' => 0, 'a' => 0))
    ->setBackgroundColor(array('r' => 255, 'g' => 255, 'b' => 255, 'a' => 0))
    ->setLabel('Scan the code')
    ->setLabelFontSize(16)
    ->setImageType(QrCode::IMAGE_TYPE_PNG)
;

// now we can directly output the qrcode
header('Content-Type: '.$qrCode->getContentType());
$qrCode->render();

// or create a response object
$response = new Response($qrCode->get(), 200, array('Content-Type' => $qrCode->getContentType()));
```

[image: The generated QRCode]

Comment: **Iwazaru** sir, how can I use `setText()` if I have **MULTIPLE** data?

For example, I have `$a = 1`, `$b = 2`, `$c = 3`?. I need to use more than **ONE** sentence or String. How can I do that?

Comment: As the `setText` method only accepts one parameters I guess you should concatenate your variables into one before passing it. But I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem correctly, maybe you should open an issue in the library's repo.

Comment: **Iwazaru** I've got the answer sir..

Comment: Wanna share it ? ;)

Comment: Sure :)  I used implode() in php to combine all data, then explode() if needed. Thats it sir :)

Comment: Also, you could use a JSON string.

Comment: The code triggers fatal error, saying: "Call to a member function setSize() on null"

Comment: In my case, I just needed to write a qr code image into the pdf. When I used header, it was directly displayed the qr code and not executed the next line of codes. There was no error or exception too. After removing the header it worked as expected.

Comment: this is not working. can you please update the code with latest library

Comment: @JigsParmar please refer to the library documentation for up-to-date examples https://github.com/endroid/QrCode

Comment: its not working. give error, can you please share working code

Answer (score 27):

The **phpqrcode library** is really fast to configure and the API documentation is easy to understand.

**In addition to abaumg's answer** I have attached 2 examples in `PHP` from http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php

**1. QR code encoder**

first include the library from your local path

```
include('../qrlib.php');
```

then to output the image directly as PNG stream do for example:

```
QRcode::png('your texte here...');
```

to save the result locally as a PNG image:

```
$tempDir = EXAMPLE_TMP_SERVERPATH;

$codeContents = 'your message here...';

$fileName = 'qrcode_name.png';

$pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
$urlRelativeFilePath = EXAMPLE_TMP_URLRELPATH.$fileName;

QRcode::png($codeContents, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
```

**2. QR code decoder**

See also the **zxing** decoder:

http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Pretty useful to check the output.

**3. List of Data format**

A list of data format you can use in your QR code according to the data type :

- Website URL: http://stackoverflow.com (including the protocole `http://`)
- email address: mailto:name@example.com
- Telephone Number: +16365553344 (including country code)
- SMS Message: smsto:number:message
- MMS Message: mms:number:subject
- YouTube Video: youtube://ID (may work on iPhone, not standardized)

Comment: this library doesnt seem to work for variety of inputs, small & simple text are okay though

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: nothing much, when i do $codeContents = "www.example.com" its ok but if i do $codeContents="www.example.com/some/view/aUdv4rP4BXXLQdpXZC6Gs5C6AfyJM4uB6ntVttIr1B0=" it did not show correct image.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. It is working fine with     QRcode::png('www.example.com/some/view/aUdv4rP4BXXLQdpXZC6Gs5C6AfyJM4uB6ntVttI‌​r1B0='); maybe it has something to do with the headers

Comment: thanks! looks like error was due to unsupported string being passed, I was using <img> src to store string. after I wrapped src parameters with urlencode() it works! I suspected because somebody here reported the library was not maintained since a while.

Comment: you are welcome. the basic features from this library are reliable but I doubt you can efficiently create fancy qrcode :)

Comment: Can i use php-qrcode library for commercial purpose like to develope a website which requires qr code in some of its part?

Comment: Good question. PHP QR Code is open source (LGPL) library. You can have a look at the terms if you want http://opensource.org/licenses/LGPL-3.0

Answer (score 14):

[qrcode-generator](https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/tree/master/php) on Github. Simplest script and works like charm.

Pros:

- No third party dependency
- No limitations for the number of QR code
  generations

Comment: I cannot find any docs on this, but it looks great!

Comment: @praba230890 could you provide some more examples with this script? i am trying to get some contact information in a QR code 300x300 px

I have installed/downloaded the script on my localhost and the sample_html.php works. But the other two not.

my japanese isn't that good (ok i will use google translate)

Comment: oh and would this be faster / better then phpqrcode library?

Comment: it's desperate.

Answer (score 6):

I know the question is how to generate QR codes using PHP, but for others who are looking for a way to generate codes for websites doing this in pure javascript is a good way to do it. The [jquery-qrcode](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode) jquery plugin does it well.

Comment: I am using the Jquery plugin https://github.com/lrsjng/jquery-qrcode for a while now, also pretty. However, output is only binary. So if you need to generate and save an image as PNG, it will not help too much. That's why most developers reading this question need PHP.

Comment: It's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906142/how-to-save-a-png-from-javascript-variable) to download a JS-generated data image 100% in the client.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant "save serverside" - not possible with only Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

I have been using google qrcode api for sometime, but I didn't quite like this because it requires me to be on the Internet to access the generated image.

I did a little comand-line research and found out that linux has a command line tool `qrencode` for generating qr-codes.

I wrote this little script. And the good part is that the generated image is less than 1KB in size. Well the supplied data is simply a url.

```
$url = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/profile.php?id='.$_GET['pid'];
$img = shell_exec('qrencode --output=- -m=1 '.escapeshellarg($url));

$imgData = "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($img);
```

Then in the html I load the image:

```
<img class="emrQRCode" src="<?=$imgData ?>" />
```

You just need to have installed it. [most imaging apps on linux would have installed it under the hood without you realizing.

Comment: escapeshellarg explained here (for those wondering) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22739494/195722 . Personally, I wouldn't shell out to a command each time (especially for a public facing generation) and I would definitely use regex to make sure what they passed in was a string that I was expecting.

Comment: works well on ubuntu 16.04