# Need advice for creating a digitized ticketing admission system

Tags: php, sql, system, qr-code

So I know this guy who runs a club on the east coast and he uses wristbands as admission for his club. He wants to get rid of these wrist bands because people have been creating phony ones.

So I plan on having every customer who buys a ticket receive an email address with a QR Code. A ticket seller would enter the customer name and email into my system I'm developing, that system will generate an alphanumeric code and create a new column in an SQL database with that customer name(String), id#(PRIMARY KEY), isVerified(boolean) and alphanumeric code.

The alphanumeric code will be used for the QR Code which will be verified at the entrance of the club.

Does anyone know if there are tutorials or guidea somewhere online for a system very similar to what I'm trying to create? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Will these tickets be single use only?

Comment: @Michael: Are you sure you didn't point that to the wrong person?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry. Autocomplete killed me there. I didn't look closely enough after I saw Matt at the beginning. I was referring to the OP of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a similar stackoverflow question (concerning QR codes):
[Dynamically generating a QR code with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php)

Concerning the system itself, you can probably use the existing system, and create the qr code based on the order_id (or something similar)