# Need QR Code Assistance for getting an admission qr code ticket

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

I have almost completed my prototype registration page for a club that wants to use QR Code verification.

So here's my prototype:
http://cinicraft.com/ticket/newcustomer.php

The prototype is run by a ticket seller whom enters customer information into the forms after a customer has paid for his or her admission. Upon completion, the ticket seller needs to be brought up to a page that simply gives a confirmation message for example:

```
Welcome James Raynor, thank you for purchasing a ticket. Here is your QR Code, use it to gain entry to the event:
```

So to keep this thread simple, I need help getting a QR Code printed with simple text(a 10 character alphanumeric string in QR Code format).

This is the code used for "http://cinicraft.com/ticket/add.php" which is brought up after filling out the forms in "http://cinicraft.com/ticket/newcustomer.php".

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return $key;
}

if($email)
{

$connect = mysql_connect("HOST", "DATABASE", "PASSWORD") or die("Couldn't Connect");

mysql_select_db("CiniCraftData") or die ("Couldn't Find Database"); 

            $query = "INSERT INTO customers (fname, lname, email, alphanum) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '" . random_string(10) . "')";

            $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Some kind of error occured.");



}
else die("You did not fill out the fields correctly, please try again.");
?>

<?php 
echo ("Welcome ");
echo ($fname);
echo (" ");
echo ($lname);
echo (", thank you for purchasing a ticket. Here is your QR Code, use it to gain entry to the event.");
?>
```

OKAY, so after all the code you see above, how could I print out a QR Code which contains a 10 character alphanumeric string?

P.S.: I'm very grateful for all the help I'm getting from this amazing community so far :)

Comment: Did you completely ignore the answer to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095442/need-advice-for-creating-a-digitized-ticketing-admission-system It has advice for doing exactly this...

Comment: I'm very new to php and mysql, I had trouble finding a way to implement that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/#demo) QR Code libary. See the documentation on its usage along the lines of this:

```
QRcode::png(random_string(10));
```

Keep in mind you should not NOT output any other content as this code will output a raw image, and any other text outputted on same page will cause it to be corrupt. So for this example put it in a file called 'qr_png.php' and then display the image such as `<img src='qr_png.php' />` you can pass the random string by $_GET query if you want.