# PHP - Custom QRCodes?

Tags: php, qr-code

I saw some online qr code generators such as https://dashboard.unitag.io/ and I was wondering how they do it.
Is it possible to do that in PHP? If so, how would I manage to do that? (I know there are some APIs to create colored QR codes and insert images into it, but I never found any that could change the 'shape' of the QR code...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically generating a QR code with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php)

Comment: Possible Duplicate Of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php

Comment: This question possibly belongs on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into a library called [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/). It's open source and is pretty simple to use,

```
QRcode::png('code data text', 'filename.png'); // creates file 
QRcode::png('some othertext 1234'); // creates code image and outputs it directly into browser
```

If you're looking for a library with a little more functionality, check out [Advanced Custom QR Code Generator](http://codecanyon.net/item/advanced-custom-qr-code-generator/5979898). It costs $35 but gives you the ability to work with shapes, colors, and even embed logos.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned, I already know about some APIs that create QR codes, but none of them can change the shape of the QR code like unitag does.

Comment: @LCastr0 I've updated my answer including another library you may want to checkout

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: the library mentioned is no longer available for sale, but it is on github - https://github.com/mahadazad/qrcode

Comment: @CFPSupport But that is a Python. Any idea of php ?