# How to build QR code using API response and PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce, payment-gateway, qr-code, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am working on new WooCommmerce payment gateway using Co2in API (https://co2in-api-devel.cleevio.io/api-docs/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=%2Fapi-docs%2Fswagger-config&urls.primaryName=v2#/Payment/qr_1)

I need to allow customers to pay by QR code. To generate it, I create a new payment, then fetch a QR. Got something like that:

```
{
  "acceleration_priority": 0,
  "color_model": {
    "transparency": 0,
    "num_components": 0,
    "num_color_components": 0,
    "color_space": {
      "type": 0,
      "num_components": 0,
      "cs_s_rgb": true
    },
    "transfer_type": 0,
    "alpha_premultiplied": true,
    "component_size": [
      0
    ],
    "pixel_size": 0
  },
  "raster": {
    "sample_model": {
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "num_bands": 0,
      "data_type": 0,
      "num_data_elements": 0,
      "sample_size": [
        0
      ],
      "transfer_type": 0
    },
    "data_buffer": {
      "data_type": 0,
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
      "offsets": [
        0
      ],
      "num_banks": 0
    },
    "min_x": 0,
    "min_y": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "sample_model_translate_x": 0,
    "sample_model_translate_y": 0,
    "num_bands": 0,
    "num_data_elements": 0,
    "parent": {
      "sample_model": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "num_bands": 0,
        "data_type": 0,
        "num_data_elements": 0,
        "sample_size": [
          0
        ],
        "transfer_type": 0
      },
      "data_buffer": {
        "data_type": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "offsets": [
          0
        ],
        "num_banks": 0
      },
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "sample_model_translate_x": 0,
      "sample_model_translate_y": 0,
      "num_bands": 0,
      "num_data_elements": 0,
      "bounds": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "size": {
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0
        },
        "empty": true,
        "location": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        },
        "bounds2_d": {
          "empty": true,
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "min_x": 0,
          "min_y": 0,
          "max_x": 0,
          "max_y": 0,
          "center_x": 0,
          "center_y": 0
        },
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "transfer_type": 0
    },
    "bounds": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "size": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0
      },
      "empty": true,
      "location": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "bounds2_d": {
        "empty": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "max_x": 0,
      "max_y": 0,
      "center_x": 0,
      "center_y": 0
    },
    "transfer_type": 0
  },
  "source": {},
  "type": 0,
  "data": {
    "sample_model": {
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "num_bands": 0,
      "data_type": 0,
      "num_data_elements": 0,
      "sample_size": [
        0
      ],
      "transfer_type": 0
    },
    "data_buffer": {
      "data_type": 0,
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
      "offsets": [
        0
      ],
      "num_banks": 0
    },
    "min_x": 0,
    "min_y": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "sample_model_translate_x": 0,
    "sample_model_translate_y": 0,
    "num_bands": 0,
    "num_data_elements": 0,
    "bounds": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "size": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0
      },
      "empty": true,
      "location": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "bounds2_d": {
        "empty": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "max_x": 0,
      "max_y": 0,
      "center_x": 0,
      "center_y": 0
    },
    "transfer_type": 0
  },
  "sources": [
    {
      "data": {
        "sample_model": {
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "num_bands": 0,
          "data_type": 0,
          "num_data_elements": 0,
          "sample_size": [
            0
          ],
          "transfer_type": 0
        },
        "data_buffer": {
          "data_type": 0,
          "offset": 0,
          "size": 0,
          "offsets": [
            0
          ],
          "num_banks": 0
        },
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "sample_model_translate_x": 0,
        "sample_model_translate_y": 0,
        "num_bands": 0,
        "num_data_elements": 0,
        "bounds": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "size": {
            "width": 0,
            "height": 0
          },
          "empty": true,
          "location": {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0
          },
          "bounds2_d": {
            "empty": true,
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "width": 0,
            "height": 0,
            "min_x": 0,
            "min_y": 0,
            "max_x": 0,
            "max_y": 0,
            "center_x": 0,
            "center_y": 0
          },
          "min_x": 0,
          "min_y": 0,
          "max_x": 0,
          "max_y": 0,
          "center_x": 0,
          "center_y": 0
        },
        "transfer_type": 0
      },
      "property_names": [
        "string"
      ],
      "sample_model": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "num_bands": 0,
        "data_type": 0,
        "num_data_elements": 0,
        "sample_size": [
          0
        ],
        "transfer_type": 0
      },
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "color_model": {
        "transparency": 0,
        "num_components": 0,
        "num_color_components": 0,
        "color_space": {
          "type": 0,
          "num_components": 0,
          "cs_s_rgb": true
        },
        "transfer_type": 0,
        "alpha_premultiplied": true,
        "component_size": [
          0
        ],
        "pixel_size": 0
      },
      "num_xtiles": 0,
      "num_ytiles": 0,
      "min_tile_x": 0,
      "min_tile_y": 0,
      "tile_width": 0,
      "tile_height": 0,
      "tile_grid_xoffset": 0,
      "tile_grid_yoffset": 0
    }
  ],
  "property_names": [
    "string"
  ],
  "alpha_premultiplied": true,
  "sample_model": {
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "num_bands": 0,
    "data_type": 0,
    "num_data_elements": 0,
    "sample_size": [
      0
    ],
    "transfer_type": 0
  },
  "alpha_raster": {
    "sample_model": {
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "num_bands": 0,
      "data_type": 0,
      "num_data_elements": 0,
      "sample_size": [
        0
      ],
      "transfer_type": 0
    },
    "data_buffer": {
      "data_type": 0,
      "offset": 0,
      "size": 0,
      "offsets": [
        0
      ],
      "num_banks": 0
    },
    "min_x": 0,
    "min_y": 0,
    "width": 0,
    "height": 0,
    "sample_model_translate_x": 0,
    "sample_model_translate_y": 0,
    "num_bands": 0,
    "num_data_elements": 0,
    "parent": {
      "sample_model": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "num_bands": 0,
        "data_type": 0,
        "num_data_elements": 0,
        "sample_size": [
          0
        ],
        "transfer_type": 0
      },
      "data_buffer": {
        "data_type": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "offsets": [
          0
        ],
        "num_banks": 0
      },
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "sample_model_translate_x": 0,
      "sample_model_translate_y": 0,
      "num_bands": 0,
      "num_data_elements": 0,
      "bounds": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "size": {
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0
        },
        "empty": true,
        "location": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        },
        "bounds2_d": {
          "empty": true,
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "min_x": 0,
          "min_y": 0,
          "max_x": 0,
          "max_y": 0,
          "center_x": 0,
          "center_y": 0
        },
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "transfer_type": 0
    },
    "bounds": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "size": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0
      },
      "empty": true,
      "location": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "bounds2_d": {
        "empty": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "max_x": 0,
      "max_y": 0,
      "center_x": 0,
      "center_y": 0
    },
    "transfer_type": 0
  },
  "width": 0,
  "height": 0,
  "min_x": 0,
  "min_y": 0,
  "transparency": 0,
  "graphics": {
    "color": {
      "red": 0,
      "green": 0,
      "blue": 0,
      "alpha": 0,
      "color_space": {
        "type": 0,
        "num_components": 0,
        "cs_s_rgb": true
      },
      "rgb": 0,
      "transparency": 0
    },
    "font": {
      "name": "string",
      "style": 0,
      "size": 0,
      "family": "string",
      "attributes": {
        "additionalProp1": {},
        "additionalProp2": {},
        "additionalProp3": {}
      },
      "transform": {
        "scale_x": 0,
        "shear_y": 0,
        "shear_x": 0,
        "scale_y": 0,
        "translate_x": 0,
        "translate_y": 0,
        "type": 0,
        "identity": true,
        "determinant": 0
      },
      "font_name": "string",
      "bold": true,
      "italic": true,
      "num_glyphs": 0,
      "missing_glyph_code": 0,
      "italic_angle": 0,
      "transformed": true,
      "psname": "string",
      "size2_d": 0,
      "plain": true,
      "available_attributes": [
        {}
      ]
    },
    "clip": {
      "bounds": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "size": {
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0
        },
        "empty": true,
        "location": {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        },
        "bounds2_d": {
          "empty": true,
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0,
          "width": 0,
          "height": 0,
          "min_x": 0,
          "min_y": 0,
          "max_x": 0,
          "max_y": 0,
          "center_x": 0,
          "center_y": 0
        },
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "bounds2_d": {
        "empty": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      }
    },
    "font_metrics": {
      "font": {
        "name": "string",
        "style": 0,
        "size": 0,
        "family": "string",
        "attributes": {
          "additionalProp1": {},
          "additionalProp2": {},
          "additionalProp3": {}
        },
        "transform": {
          "scale_x": 0,
          "shear_y": 0,
          "shear_x": 0,
          "scale_y": 0,
          "translate_x": 0,
          "translate_y": 0,
          "type": 0,
          "identity": true,
          "determinant": 0
        },
        "font_name": "string",
        "bold": true,
        "italic": true,
        "num_glyphs": 0,
        "missing_glyph_code": 0,
        "italic_angle": 0,
        "transformed": true,
        "psname": "string",
        "size2_d": 0,
        "plain": true,
        "available_attributes": [
          {}
        ]
      },
      "height": 0,
      "font_render_context": {
        "transform": {
          "scale_x": 0,
          "shear_y": 0,
          "shear_x": 0,
          "scale_y": 0,
          "translate_x": 0,
          "translate_y": 0,
          "type": 0,
          "identity": true,
          "determinant": 0
        },
        "anti_aliasing_hint": {},
        "fractional_metrics_hint": {},
        "transformed": true,
        "anti_aliased": true,
        "transform_type": 0
      },
      "ascent": 0,
      "descent": 0,
      "leading": 0,
      "max_descent": 0,
      "widths": [
        0
      ],
      "max_ascent": 0,
      "max_decent": 0,
      "max_advance": 0
    },
    "clip_bounds": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "size": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0
      },
      "empty": true,
      "location": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "bounds2_d": {
        "empty": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "max_x": 0,
      "max_y": 0,
      "center_x": 0,
      "center_y": 0
    },
    "clip_rect": {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0,
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "size": {
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0
      },
      "empty": true,
      "location": {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
      },
      "bounds2_d": {
        "empty": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "min_x": 0,
        "min_y": 0,
        "max_x": 0,
        "max_y": 0,
        "center_x": 0,
        "center_y": 0
      },
      "min_x": 0,
      "min_y": 0,
      "max_x": 0,
      "max_y": 0,
      "center_x": 0,
      "center_y": 0
    }
  },
  "num_xtiles": 0,
  "num_ytiles": 0,
  "min_tile_x": 0,
  "min_tile_y": 0,
  "tile_width": 0,
  "tile_height": 0,
  "tile_grid_xoffset": 0,
  "tile_grid_yoffset": 0,
  "writable_tile_indices": [
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

How to generate a png of QR code using this? Thanks.

Comment: I think it could be a useful link:
[dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php)

Comment: I think it could be a useful link: [dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943368/dynamically-generating-a-qr-code-with-php)