# This exec() is secure?

Tags: php, security

I have this code :

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd($_GET['command']);
$cmd2 = escapeshellcmd($_GET['command2']);
exec("program" . $cmd . $cmd2);
```

And I want know if is secure to allow any person to use it with an html form ?

Comment: We don't know what `program` does.

Comment: is a tool can't have impact on the system (imapsync)

Comment: I dont know enough about this, but it seems pretty unsafe. How about I say `&& touch myprog.sh && echo "my program code" >> myprog.sh`?

Comment: Is because I use escapeshellcmd()

Comment: for arguments use escapeshellarg

Comment: You are executing `"program$cmd$cmd2"`, not `"program $cmd $cmd2"`. And if you have to ask then it is probably not secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, don't let using `escapeshellcmd` or `escapeshellarg` give you a false sense of security. Passing values directly to the commandline **even escaped** without any form of validation is asking for trouble.

If you are adamant I'd advise reading the following discussion:

[What's the difference between escapeshellarg and escapeshellcmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881582/whats-the-difference-between-escapeshellarg-and-escapeshellcmd)

Comment: +1 for a strict NO. OP, you should _always_ whitelist arguments explicitly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any idea to secure this part of code ?

Comment: @skyice Benjamin just told you: white list the allowed arguments

Comment: @skyice you should read the link I posted for advise on doing it too

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist allowed commands.

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd($_GET['command']);
$cmd2 = escapeshellcmd($_GET['command2']);
$allowed_cmds = array('ls', 'foo', ...);

if(in_array($cmd, $allowed_cmds)) {
    if(in_array($cmd2, $allowed_cmds)) {
        exec("program" . $cmd . $cmd2);
    }
}
```

Personally though, you are doing something wrong. I've written socket systems, websites, database abstractions, language processing libraries, email servers, regex parsers, and a whole slue of other things.

I've never needed the nasty, slow `exec`.

Comment: You probably meant to use `escapeshellarg` and you need to add spaces to the exec. It's clear you haven't used it very often. :)

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton, that's what I get for cheating. I just copied the OP's code and throw in the conditional. I learned my lesson.