# Run Python function with arguments using PHP

Tags: python, php, terminal

My goal is to run different Python functions with different arguments on a click of a HTML(PHP) button.
When i execute the command in the terminal everything works fine (lights turn on)

```
# terminal
python3 -c 'from lights import *; lights.turn_on_group("bath")'
```

but when i try to run the same command in PHP there happens nothing (blank page).

```
# test.php

$cmd = "python3 -c 'from lights import *; lights.turn_on_group(\"bath\")'";
$command = escapeshellcmd($cmd);
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you add php file this `print "<pre>$output</pre>";` code so we can see clearly whats the problem it is.

Comment: @Orhan There is a empty output -> "<pre></pre>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is being caused due to the statement `escapeshellcmd($cmd)`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881582/whats-the-difference-between-escapeshellarg-and-escapeshellcmd) your command separator character is being escaped due to security reasons hence not being interpreted by shell, Now you are left with two options

**OPTION 1**

Remove the statement or simply do not escape your command, in your case its safe because you are executing hard coded command not a command taken from user. so no need to escape it.

*example*

```
$cmd = "python3 -c 'from lights import *; lights.turn_on_group(\"bath\")'";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
```

**OPTION 2**

Just in case if you are too much willing to implement standards and use that function then wrap your code into a single python script e.g. `myLights.py` then call your script with arguments it will work because command separator will not be needed!

*example `myLights.py`*

```
import sys
from lights import *

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    lights.turn_on_group(sys.argv[1])
    print('lights turned on')
else
    print('No input received')
```

and to call it

```
python3 myLights.py bath
```

e.g.

```
$cmd = "python3 myLights.py bath";
$command = escapeshellcmd($cmd); #no special characters it will work
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

I would suggest you using this method as you will get more customizations and options added in just single command line call with security layers active.